# What is a better way to construct Linked Lists?

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I have been trying to construct a linked list where there are 3 different ways to view the code, either the current double value or the previous or next node. The problem I seem to be running into is that in essecense I have been creating a new linked list whenever storing the next or previous node of the current node rather than linking it.

This creates 2 problems:

1. It takes up a ridicolous amount of space
2. It creates makes bugs and errors common and hard to spot

I want to know if there is a better way to construct linked lists than this method or if I am running into these 2 problems for reasons different than I believe. My code is down below if you want to see what I have been trying to do.

```java
package algs662;

import java.util.*;

//This whole file is about assembling and sorting data
public class BigSort 
{
  //The Node is an element that represents the current position
  //of a linked list and what is immediately to its left or right static class Node 
  {
    //this represents the Node itself
    public Node() { }
    //this represents its current element
    public double item;
    //this represents the node to its right
    public Node next;
    //this represents the node to its left
    public Node prev;
  }

  //this represents the size of the Linked List
  int N;
  //this is the main node
  Node first;
  //this is a variable that will be false when the function
  //using this hasn't ran once and will be true when it has
  public boolean once = false;
    
  //This will create an empty node where new elements can be added
  public BigSort() 
  {
    first = null;
    N = 0;
    checkInvariants ();
  }
    
  //This represents the max value
  static double max;
  private void myassert( String s, boolean b ) 
  { 
    if( !b ) throw new AssertionError( "Assertion failed: " + s ); 
  }
  
  private void checkInvariants() 
  {
    myassert( "Empty <==> first==null", (N == 0) == (first == null) );
    Node x = first;
    for( int i = 0; i < N; ++i ) 
    {
      if( x==null ) 
      {
        throw new Error( "List too short!" );
      }
      x = x.next;
    }
    myassert("EndOfList == null", x == null);
  }
    
  private Node reset( Node n ) 
  {
    Node saved;
    while( n.prev != null ) 
    {
      saved = n;
      n =  n.prev;
    }
    return n;
  }
    
  //This function will delete a specific number from a list
  private void delete( double num ) 
  {
    if( once == false ) 
    {
      Node curr = first;
      if( N == 0 ) { throw new Error( "There is no list" ); }
      else if( N == 1 ) 
      {
        if( curr.item == num ) 
        {
          first = null;
          return;
        }
        else 
        {
          throw new Error( "Number inputted doesn't exist" );
        }
      }
      else if( curr != null )
      {
        if( curr.item == num ) 
        {
          first = curr.next;
          --N;
          return;
        }
        while( curr.next != null ) 
        {
          if( curr.next.item != num ) 
          {
            curr.prev = curr;
            curr = curr.next;
          }
          else if( curr.next.item == num ) 
          {
            curr.next = curr.next.next;
            --N;
            reset( curr );
            return;
          }
        }
        if( curr.item == num ) 
        {
          first = curr.prev;
          curr.next = null;
          --N;
          reset( curr );
          return;
        }
        else if( curr.next == null )
        {
          throw new Error( "Number inputted doesn't exist" );
        }
      }
    }
    else 
    {
      return;
    }
  }
  
  private void push( double i ) 
  {
    Node temp = new Node();
    temp.item = i;
    Node saved;
    Node curr = first;
    if( this.first == null ) 
    {
      first = temp;
      return;
    }
    else 
    {
      while( curr.next != null ) 
      {
        saved = curr;
        curr = curr.next;
        curr.prev = saved;
      }
      saved = curr;
      curr.next = temp;
      curr = curr.next;
      curr.prev = saved;
    }
    this.N++;
    first = reset( curr );
  }
  
  private void pushFront( double i ) 
  {
    Node temp = new Node();
    Node saved;
    temp.item = i;
    temp.next = first;
    saved = temp;
    temp = temp.next;
    temp.prev = saved;
    temp = temp.prev;
    ++N;
    first = temp;
  }
  
  private void pushPos( int pos, double i )
  {
    Node temp = new Node();
    Node store = new Node();
    Node last = new Node();
    store.item = i;
    temp = first;
    Node saved;
    double pastval;
    double savedval;
    if( pos > N || pos < 0 ) 
    {
      throw new Error( "The position inputted doesn't exist" );
    }
    else 
    {
      if( pos == 0 ) 
      {
        store.item = i;
        store.next = first;
        ++N;
        first = store;
        return;
      }
      for( int x = 0; x < pos; ++x ) 
      {
        saved = temp;
        temp = temp.next;
        temp.prev = saved;
      }
      pastval = temp.item;
      temp.item = i;
      temp = temp.next;
      savedval = temp.item;
      temp.item = pastval;
      while( temp.next != null ) 
      {
        // Does nothing??
      }
      first=reset( temp );
      return;
    }
  }
  
  private double pop() 
  {
    Node popped;
    Node temp = first;
    while( temp.next.next !=null ) 
    {
      temp = temp.next;
    }
    popped = temp.next;
    temp.next = null;
    --N;
    System.out.print( popped );
    first = temp;
    return popped.item;
  }
  
  private void incurSort() 
  {
    double swap = 0;
    int u = 0;
    for( int y = 1; y < N - 1; ++y )
    {
      //this compares the current item to the next item
      if( first.item > first.next.item ) 
      {
        u = y;
        while( u > 0 && first.prev != null ) 
        {
          if( first.item > first.next.item ) 
          {
            swap = first.item;
            first.item = first.next.item;
            first.next.item = swap;
          }
          first =  first.prev;
          --u;
        }
      }
      while( u < y && first.next != null )
      {
        first = first.next;
        ++u;
      }
    }
    reset(first);
  }

  public static void main( String args[] )
  {
    double swap = 0;
    BigSort b = new BigSort();
    int u = 0;
    // Adding elements in the list
    // using add() method
    b.push( 1.0 );
    b.push( 3.0 );
    b.push( 5.0 );
    b.push( 2.0 );
    b.push( 20.0 );
    b.push( 11.0 );
    b.push( 13.0 );
    b.push( 17.0 );

    Node two = b.first;
    b.incurSort();
    b.delete( 11.0 );
    b.delete( 1.0);
    b.delete( 20.0);
    b.delete( 5.0);
    b.delete( 3.0);
    b.delete( 13.0);

    b.pushFront( 10.0);
    b.pushFront( 2.0 );
    b.pushFront( 16.0 );
    b.pushFront( 50.0 );
    b.pushFront( 100.0 );
    b.pushPos( 2, 20.0 );

    System.out.println( b.pop() );
    System.out.println( b.pop() );
    System.out.println( b.pop() );
    System.out.println( b.pop() );
    System.out.println( b.pop() );
    System.out.println( b.pop() );
    System.out.println( "stuff left over" );
    for( int k = 0; k <= b.N - 1; ++k )
    {
      if( b.first != null ) 
      {
        System.out.println( b.first.item );
        b.first = b.first.prev;
      }
      else 
      {
        System.out.println( "it broke at " + k );
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Checkout https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ that is really a great place to ask these kind of questions :)

Comment: First: to compare two `double` values with `==` may work – or not! It depends from where the value originate.